# Paginate custom queryset based on object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've got following API View with custom queryset based on object. I'm getting object by `pk` provided in url.
I want to return all related instances for object with pagination.

```
class ListVotedAPIView(generics.ListAPIView, VoteModelMixin):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.voted(request)

    def get_queryset(self):
        instance = self.get_object()
        return services.get_voted(instance)

class VoteModelMixin:
    def voted(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And here is `services.get_voted()`:

```
def get_voted(obj):
    """
    Return all users that voted `obj`.
    """
    obj_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)
    return User.objects.filter(
        votes__content_type=obj_type,
        votes__object_id=obj.id
    )
```

The problem is that `get_object()` is defined in terms of `get_queryset()`

And I'm getting the following error: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`
How can I override `get_object()` method which will be able to work with different models?

**UPDATED**

```
class CommentLikeAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView, ):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LikeSerializer

    @staticmethod
    def get_contenttype():
        return ContentType.objects.get(model='comment')

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        """
        Extra context provided to the serializer class.
        """
        return {'request': self.request,
                'format': self.format_kwarg,
                'view': self,
                'content_type': self.get_contenttype(),
                'pk': self.kwargs.get('pk')}
```

Comment: The problem is that `get_object` is defined in terms of `get_queryset`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So the solution is to override get_object()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you define `get_queryset` in terms of `get_object`, but `get_object` is defined as:

> ```
> def get_object(self):
>     # ...
>     queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
>
>     # Perform the lookup filtering.
>     lookup_url_kwarg = self.lookup_url_kwarg or self.lookup_field
>
>     assert lookup_url_kwarg in self.kwargs, (
>         'Expected view %s to be called with a URL keyword argument '
>         'named "%s". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` '
>         'attribute on the view correctly.' %
>         (self.__class__.__name__, lookup_url_kwarg)
>     )
>
>     filter_kwargs = {self.lookup_field: self.kwargs[lookup_url_kwarg]}
>     obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs)
>
>     # May raise a permission denied
>     self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
>
>     return obj
> ```

So that means that `.get_queryset(..)` will call `.get_object(..)` that will then call `.get_queryset(..)` again, and this will go on, until eventually it results in the call stack overflowing.

So you will somehow need to break this *mutual recursion*, for example by implementing a `get_queryset` that does *not* depend on `get_object`, or by overwriting a `get_object` that does *not* depend on `get_queryset`.

For example something like:

```
def get_object(self):
    # ...
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(this.model.objects.all())
    # ...
    return get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs)
```

(given that you will only provide a `Model`, so perhaps you need to implement something more sophisticated).

> **Note**: you probably want to pass `*args` and `**kwargs` in `.get(..)` as well, like:
>
> ```
> def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>     return self.voted(request, *args, **kwargs)
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Will it be optimal decision to provide `model` param to each APIView where I'm using such a logic?
I've already has some endpoints that uses this logic but they aren't optimal enough for me. Added in **UPDATED** section my solution

Comment: @Ernst: not per se, you might create a `get_inner_queryset` and thus use that one for the "original" queryset. This can be implemented in the way it is implemented in a `ListView`, etc. So then you have the freedom to specify a `model`, `queryset`, and `get_inner_queryset`.

Comment: @Ernst: for your case you could `queryset = self.filter_queryset(this.queryset)` and then post-process it.